# AndroidJUnitRunner - Does it run test cases in any specific order?

Tags: android, android-testing, androidjunitrunner

Does `AndroidJUnitRunner` runs test cases in any specific order? Or the run of test cases are random?
For example, if my test class has 5 test cases, then what will be the order of execution of those cases?

Answer (score 1):

Just like normal Junit tests, AndroidJUnit runner cases also doesn't have any specific order.